# Finding convergence of two similarly looking logarithmic series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm given two *similarly* looking series $\sum_{n = 3}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln\ln n)^{\ln n}}$ and $\sum_{n = 3}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln\ln n}}$. My tip is that first is convergent, while second is divergent, but I don't know how to show it rigorously.

What are some ways to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first series, note that
$$ (\ln\ln n)^{\ln n}=\exp(\ln n\ln\ln\ln n)\geq \exp(2\ln n)=n^2$$
for all sufficiently large $n$. So the series in question converges by comparison with $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$.

For the second, 
$$ (\ln n)^{\ln\ln n}=\exp\big[(\ln\ln n)^2\big]\leq \exp(\ln n)=n$$
for all sufficiently large $n$. So the series diverges by comparison with $\sum\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Is $1/(\ln \ln n)^{\ln n} \le 1/n^2$ for large $n?$ Is $1/(\ln n)^{\ln \ln n} \ge 1/n$ for large $n?$